# Is it possible to intercept the web request under IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have deploy some web service under port `80` using IIS, like:

```
http://localhost/service1/
http://localhost/service2/
...
```

Now we want to do some statistics and authentication job for these services, now I have two ideas:

1 change each service

Add the statistics and authentication login one by one.

But I think this is not a good idea since we have so many application to be updated, and these codes are repeated seriously.

2 Create a separate application.

This application should can intercept each request of the services, and do the related job. And we can add other features for this application someday.

This is the flexible way I think. But I am not sure if this is possible?

BTW, the url of the deployed services can not be changed.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best pet is to create a HTTP Module, then add this module to your apps,  which will then be able to intercept every request coming to it's hosting application.

From the official page

> An HTTP module is an assembly that is called on every request made to
>   your application. HTTP modules are called as part of the ASP.NET
>   request pipeline and have access to life cycle events throughout the
>   request. HTTP modules therefore give you the opportunity to examine
>   incoming requests and take action based on the request. They also give
>   you the opportunity to examine the outbound response and modify it.

more on this topic can be found via the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178468(v=vs.85).aspx

a walk through of creating a simple HTTP Module
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx

as part of the same topic of intercepting calls, I hihgly recommend you to read the following article describing the various aspects of both HTTP Handlers & HTTP Modules.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx

**Update**
as per your comment, you will need to create an ISAPI filter, which is similar to the descried technique of HTTP Module, but can be on the IIS level instead of the Application level. more can be found about this way here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610(v=vs.90).aspx

but note that you cannot use your existing skills to write such filter, as it only supports programming using C/C++.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Maybe I do not make me clear, the services are under different application like this http://pbrd.co/1iyeCiY  Does the http module work on this suitation?

Comment: Thank you, I will have a try.