# Is it possible to intercept the encrypted HTTP body in Biztalk AS2 connection?

Tags: iis, biztalk

Is it possible to see the full HTTP request that was made towards an AS2 endpoint?

I tried Failed requests tracing from IIS but it does not show the body (probably because it is encrypted).

I would like to be able to replay the AS2 call using something like this:

```
POST http://aaa.com/PARTY/BTSHTTPReceive.dll HTTP/1.1

Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name="smime.p7m"

Disposition-Notification-Options: signed-receipt-protocol=required,pkcs7-signature; signed-receipt-
micalg=required,sha1

AS2-Version: 1.2

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Mime-Version: 1.0

Receipt-Delivery-Option: http://IPADDRESS/BiztalkMDN/BTSHTTPReceive.dll

EDIINT-Features: multiple-attachments

AS2-To: SOURCE

Message-ID: <NC-AZ-HQ-BZ-ACC_19ED90F5-1E8F-455F-A800-22917F2C5DF0>

AS2-From: DESTINATION

Disposition-Notification-To: http://IPADRESS/BiztalkMDN/BTSHTTPReceive.dll

User-Agent: Microsoft (R) BizTalk (R) Server
Host: ...
Content-Length: 2509
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Close

0       * H  
     0    1 Q0 M 050!10Uaaa.com-   JΎKJ 7J- *0
    * H  

 f  m  zG$  jF9 Q1 :  d, =  T ׻r  E  5    C  @/  qx  M kR  [   mV        / NǦ ÿ  
  a.   =]: {yB_sgV [  `o  zڛN L  1 ߭  R q  jUۮy '/ p 7t :ƒ* l/Q "  O QCF \    =cA#  j (mV m x  3  =  'P  & m(RR҉h0  K       ) + @F pˮ  PU0 Z   * H  
 0* H  
0
:  5& c.퀂0—D w |  Θ y   cO2 M    z< pQL  m    7 +%b fH   *`f 8͚ ~=ԙ4b &9!  b B # l1  "     z   \  Q  S- . } "        cZv    >N.n%  ̰|    3 a:  :[1ӏZ k   ,    W      ̩J  qjʉ   =%7  
  7 l m  ׵ 
 b Inx : =Q  p 1 + Gs 
:)   T; .O  Uf Chڑ   i , E    HV+ ߣ  G d g „{  V. e Q .L  <   vx    T 
;  t  <  pA

 j^J T  O_  9* [v=g4l c  `5  Ԃ' H YS]߉ ' Ob  $ 3   z 4  5    2  \3$IL   :  :  T iy7; ԊE Z!{ 
   [   \@x  w  k(  OaaZ:    | / h"  U :! \u    4  V  8    v " M ϙv   x "zL… p yĹ   2> +"p Ċ > t>  v   ӎ  j l
  ąN)j  , { ǗG5 +UK   y   ~    9 ڣ: A ֙  (#  Չ    4
  !   .7y Aۣ   .   J   j  bhX   .-j )  Z8( m^{=t哑[ |  ^ Z )U 0[9V    5   L R3 , o   ՝fj  H!x  1J6    ( [F N <oq I    ͓C a ': ˅  Ϊ ss{  ? hJ46 {  Y>1  @-  ֳ}  9* ʪ   z tW U  g8   o
De  b )   0SD6  7  )  I N  yW| f    s e qUz.q 55  ]!  2 y 'Ў  F)  y    e @ F a3   h
<k1 s  3 5 6   2 >6 2I5z|SNY  /  e 2?P ѽ. -U  +    
    h   x >2 m/Œ  f  cYSD  ˇA 2u +   '       7CDT"@
  h %; ~x   R g    Y K %>  ?g|   +h-:<  ,  vT( c!1J   h5    0 )  j   T G  1 ʋL  * ad     0pAv~XS      -   #    ' gK~  u  +fS |   zr   U U    ҽ  C   @@m ӑ   $   K    CZ ̀ Y MixO  8 @ IB   %WwT: H M2 >˪ R Myn 0h$    9@    '    τ 7=+Vюx `      W{ b P  Ob
KB 
"қ    pýG ;= 2UD ]ƜY+ bZ8) R +ٔL    t QN        Q 
4ڎ  @nJ+byK  A p   ,  U  FS`i  wY`  U NwƽU<  27    ]*  { 'CV  ?QǓ  L=`@C  (!  ^ 7k   EJ? $   C )% f=  A x    L )^P t  !Tu
~^A] 8"    E/: t 3   P  5iG@     "|J  &   U [MC    $WUS&g  %h)5 Ę mI  ~   ÷  /mC  Mq nNĝ Ǩ j  *. }o E/ y  G  ד 1   h  ?D  m %˷ ^ DXy-  mj_  [ dT  
SM珍
 k?[       - i ;   3i  B[W͵ <w R    YP; KGaF . Up}^ : .W "   3 뙲E _ hI   }
   SG  3  ι     Œ hd  *   ++_Gz bc;    D  @   
 و  y p ۧy   A   D   k   ŧ ?  5 t ^ <. . I'  .Vp /&nVo N y0  b  K 0         3QE 
L vw tθ    S     /w 9 K նB  x2Q@+Tj  fC F R  c  
<Ad/ 1tlSfպ- w O0o  =)  T鏺 Q
```

Comment: You would have to use something like Wireshark, or Fiddler.  But to actually replay the message you would basically have to do a Man In The Middle Attack type setup.   What is the issue you are actually trying to solve?  Can't you get the original sender to resend?

Comment: We can have the client resend, but that is not always the best approach. There are tools like Biztalk 360 which are able to reprocess the message and we were wondering how those are working.

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei you could try to use the HTTP Module.add this module to your apps, which will then be able to intercept every request coming to it's hosting application.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632214/is-it-possible-to-intercept-the-web-request-under-iis

Comment: I think you can see the request body IF there a module that uses a notification to read the body, regardless of HTTPS, but if it is encrypted by the application then it probably won't work.  I've created a 'Failed Request Trace Viewer' and I'd love some constructive feedback if anyone is interested in trying it.  https://github.com/brian2github/FailedRequestTraceViewer

Comment: You might be interested in the latest update from BizTalk360  https://blogs.biztalk360.com/biztalk360-v9-1-new-features-enhancements/?utm_source=release-newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=release-v9.1   • View MDN Message in EDI AS2 - EDI AS2/MDN message content can be viewed as an encoded and wired format.